# Switching from pause to play button after the song automatically

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, html5-audio

I've got a tiny problem with my custom HTML MP3 player. After the player finishes the song, the pause button is still there, although there should be the play button so you can play the song again by clicking it.

Here's my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function play() {
      document.getElementById("player").play();
      document.getElementById("pausebutton").style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("playbutton").style.display = "none";
    }

    function pause() {
      document.getElementById("player").pause();
      document.getElementById("playbutton").style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("pausebutton").style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="play()">

  <audio id="player">
       <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>

      </audio>
  <img src="play.png" onclick="play()" id="playbutton" style="display: none" />
  <img src="pause.png" onclick="pause()" id="pausebutton" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look into the "ended" event on the audio tag/element. Here are few [examples](http://forestmist.org/blog/html5-audio-loops/)

Comment: @i-- document.getElementById("player").addEventListener('ended', function pause(); can i do this?

Comment: Yes, as long as you target IE9 or greater. Otherwise, you can just do `document.getElementById("player").onended = function ...`

Comment: @i-- in which function should i put this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the following within your script tag:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    if (player) {
        player.onended = function () {
            pause();
            player.currentTime = 0;
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: mh, that does'nt work. sound cannot be played anymore EDIT: I was mistaken. sound is working

Comment: Your can try to add `player.currentTime = 0;` below or above the `pause();` line.

Comment: Updated the code in the answer (note removal of the `if (player.onended)` part).